# NPE after grails clean

Tags: grails

The application works just fine, but after grails clean it starts throwing an error if I execute grails war or grail web-app:

```
|Loading Grails 2.4.3
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to production
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
..
|Compiling 18 source files
.Error 
|
Compilation error: startup failed:
General error during class generation: NPE while processing BcvjobService.groovy

groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: NPE while processing BcvjobService.groovy
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitClass(AsmClassGenerator.java:252)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$16.call(CompilationUnit.java:805)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1047)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:583)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:561)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:538)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:517)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.compile(FileSystemCompiler.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.doCompilation(FileSystemCompiler.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.runCompiler(Groovyc.java:1161)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.compile(Groovyc.java:1212)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.Grailsc.compile(Grailsc.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.execute(Groovyc.java:827)
```

...

Googling didn't help in the least, so I can't even understand where to start, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is BcvjobService.groovy:

```
 package bcvapp

import grails.transaction.Transactional
import groovy.lang.Closure;
import groovy.io.FileType
import groovy.util.AntBuilder

import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import grails.util.Mixin
import grails.util.Holders

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder as SCH



@Transactional
@Mixin(ServiceCategory)
class BcvjobService {

    def mailService
    def holderService
    def servletContext = SCH.servletContext
    def String absPath = getAbsPath()
    def String configPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/pipeline/bcvrun.prj.xml")

    def outputMap = [:]


    def prepareDirectory(Bcvjob job, String sessionId, List fileList, List directionList, Integer queueSize){

        def configFile = new File (configPath)

        def defaultConfig = new XmlParser().parse(configFile)


        //  Create directory structure

        def inputLine  = defaultConfig.BCV_Input
        def input = inputLine.text().replaceAll(Pattern.compile('[\\.\\/\\\\]'), '')

        def outputLine  = defaultConfig.BCV_Output
        def output = outputLine.text().replaceAll(Pattern.compile('[\\.\\/\\\\]'), '')

        def folderPath = "${absPath}${sessionId}"
        def inputPath = folderPath + "/" + input
        def outputPath = folderPath + "/" + output

        addResultsPath(sessionId, outputPath)

        inputLine[0].value = inputPath
        outputLine[0].value = outputPath

        def inpath  = defaultConfig.InPath // why there are two almost identical lines in bcv config?
        inpath[0].value = inputPath

        new File (inputPath).mkdirs()
        new File (outputPath).mkdir()

        new File(outputPath + "/simple_results.html").createNewFile()
        File res = new File(outputPath + "/simple_results.html")
        if (queueSize > 2 ){
            res << ("Your task was submitted at  ${new Date()}<p>") 
            res << ("Waiting in queue..<p>")
            res << ("Please, bookmark this page to see the results later. Refresh the page to check if they are ready.")
        }
        else {
            res << ("Your task was submitted at  ${new Date()}<p>") 
            res << ("Running..<p>")
            res << ("Please, bookmark this page to see the results later. Refresh the page to check if they are ready.")    
        }

        res << ("<script>")
        res << ("var interval = setInterval('location.reload()', '30000');")
        res << ("</script>")


        for (f in fileList){
            new File (outputPath + "/" + f.getOriginalFilename().replaceAll(Pattern.compile('\\..*'), '').replaceAll("\\s+", "_")).mkdir()
        }

        uploadFiles(inputPath, fileList)



        // Write custom configuration file



        def vocabulary = defaultConfig.Vocabulary
        def vocabularyPath = vocabulary[0].text().substring(0, vocabulary[0].text().lastIndexOf("/")+1)
        def vocabularyName = job.vocabulary.replaceAll(/\s+/, "_")
        vocabulary[0].value = vocabularyPath + vocabularyName + ".seq.fas"

        def reads = defaultConfig.READS.find{'READS'}
        reads.children.clear()

        def counter = 0
        for (f in fileList){
            def stringDirection
            if (directionList.get(counter) == "r"){
                stringDirection = "reverse"
            }
            else stringDirection = "forward"
            reads.appendNode('Read', [name:f.getOriginalFilename().replaceAll("\\s+", "_")]).appendNode('Direction', stringDirection)
            counter++
        }


        def taxdb = defaultConfig.Database
        if (job.taxdb == "full"){
            taxdb[0].value = "all"
        }
        else if (job.taxdb == "named isolates"){
            taxdb[0].value = "named"
        }

        def distance = defaultConfig.DistanceThreshold
        distance[0].value = job.distance.toFloat()

        def email = defaultConfig.Email
        email[0].value = job.email

        def mode = defaultConfig.Mode
        mode[0].value = "PIPELINE"

        def writer = new StringWriter()
        def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer))
        printer.with {
            preserveWhitespace = true
            expandEmptyElements = true
        }
        printer.print(defaultConfig)
        def result = writer.toString()
        new File(folderPath + "/bcvrun.prj.xml").write(result)

        return outputPath

    }



    def Closure getWaitingPipeline = {Bcvjob job ->

        def queueSize = Bcvjob.countByDateCreatedLessThanEquals(job.dateCreated) + Stapjob.countByDateCreatedLessThanEquals(job.dateCreated)

        if(queueSize > 2){
            println (" bcv waiting in queue; sessionId ${job.sessionId} time ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
            while (queueSize > 2){  // 1 running task + our task
                sleep(5000)
                queueSize = Bcvjob.countByDateCreatedLessThanEquals(job.dateCreated) + Stapjob.countByDateCreatedLessThanEquals(job.dateCreated)
            }
            println (" bcv finished waiting in queue; sessionId ${job.sessionId} time ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")


            def res = new File(getResults(job.sessionId)).newWriter() 
                res.write("Your task was submitted at  ${new Date()}<p>") 
                res.write("Running..<p>")
                res.write("Please, bookmark this page to see the results later. Refresh the page to check if they are ready.")
                res.close()
            }

        def returnCode = runPipeline(job.sessionId)
        println (" bcv waiting pipeline finished; sessionId ${job.sessionId} time ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")

        if (returnCode != 143){
            zipResults(job.sessionId)
            println (" bcv waiting results zipped; sessionId ${job.sessionId} time ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
        }

        if (returnCode == 0){

            if (job.email) {
                sendResults(job.email, job.sessionId)
                println (" bcv waiting results sent; sessionId ${job.sessionId} time ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
            }
        }
        else {
            if (job.email) {
                sendLogs(job.email, job.sessionId)
                println (" bcv bad news sent; sessionId ${job.sessionId} time ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
            }
            else if (returnCode != 143) {
                sendLogs(job.sessionId) // send to weidewind
            }
            else {
                println (" user left; sessionId ${job.sessionId} ")
            }
        }

        def sessionId =  job.sessionId
        job.delete(flush:true)
        holderService.setDone(sessionId)
    }


    def Closure getPipeline = {Bcvjob job ->

        def returnCode = runPipeline(job.sessionId)
        println (" bcv pipeline finished; sessionId ${job.sessionId} time ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
        if (returnCode != 143){
            zipResults(job.sessionId)
            println (" bcv results zipped; sessionId ${job.sessionId} time ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
        }

        if (returnCode == 0){

            if (job.email) {
                sendResults(job.email, job.sessionId)
                println (" bcv results sent; sessionId ${job.sessionId} time ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
            }
        }
        else {
            if (job.email) {
                sendLogs(job.email, job.sessionId, returnCode)
                println (" bcv bad news sent; sessionId ${job.sessionId} time ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
            }
            else if (returnCode != 143) {
                sendLogs(job.sessionId) // send to weidewind
            }
            else {
                println (" user left; sessionId ${job.sessionId} ")
            }
        }

        def sessionId =  job.sessionId
        job.delete(flush:true)
        holderService.setDone(sessionId)

    }

    private def addResultsPath(String sessionId, String outputPath){
        outputMap.putAt(sessionId, outputPath)
    }


    def runPipeline(String sessionId){

        println (" going to run bcv pipeline, sessionId ${sessionId}")
        def command = "perl /store/home/popova/Programs/BCV_pipeline/pipeline.pl ${absPath}${sessionId} bcvrun.prj.xml >${absPath}pipelinelog.txt >2${absPath}pipelinerr.txt"// Create the String

            holderService.procs[sessionId] = command.execute()                 // Call *execute* on the string
            holderService.procs[sessionId].consumeProcessOutput( System.out, System.err ) //31.10
            holderService.procs[sessionId].waitFor()                               // Wait for the command to finish

        def exitValue = holderService.procs[sessionId].exitValue()
        println "return code " +  exitValue
        holderService.deleteProc(sessionId)
        return exitValue
    }


    def uploadFiles(String uploadPath, List fileList){

        for (f in fileList){
            if(f instanceof org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile){

                def fileName = f.getOriginalFilename().replaceAll("\\s+", "_")
                new FileOutputStream(uploadPath + "/" + fileName).leftShift( f.getInputStream() )

            } else {
                log.error("wrong attachment type [${f.getClass()}]");
            }
        }
    }

    def uploadSequenceFiles(String uploadPath, List fileList){
        for (f in fileList){
            if(f instanceof org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile){

                def fileName = f.getOriginalFilename().replaceAll("\\s+", "_")
                new FileOutputStream(uploadPath + "/" + fileName.replaceAll(Pattern.compile('\\..*'), '') + "/" + fileName).leftShift( f.getInputStream() )

            } else {
                log.error("wrong attachment type [${f.getClass()}]");
            }
        }
    }


    def sendResults(String email, String sessionId) {

        def results = getZipResults(sessionId)
        println "going to send files, sessionID ${sessionId} resultsPath ${results} time ${System.currentTimeMillis()}"

        mailService.sendMail {
            multipart true
            to email
            subject "BCV results"
            body "Thanks for using BCV!\n Here are your results. \n Have a nice day!"
            attachBytes 'results.zip','application/zip', new File(results).readBytes()

        }

    }

    def sendExampleResults(String email, String folderName){
        def results = getStorePath() + folderName + "/results.zip"
        println "going to send files, folderName ${folderName} resultsPath ${results} time ${System.currentTimeMillis()}"

        mailService.sendMail {
            multipart true
            to email
            subject "Example BCV results"
            body "Thanks for using BCV!\n Here are your example results. \n Have a nice day!"
            attachBytes 'results.zip','application/zip', new File(results).readBytes()

        }
    }

    def sendLogs(String email, String sessionId) {

        //def logs = "${absPath}${sessionId}logfile"
        def results = getZipResults(sessionId)
        println "going to send logs, sessionID ${sessionId} logPath ${logs} time ${System.currentTimeMillis()}"

        mailService.sendMail {
            multipart true
            to email
            subject "BCV failed"
            body "We are very sorry, but something has gone amiss. Here are some of your results, though."
            attachBytes 'results.zip','application/zip', new File(results).readBytes()
        }
        //just in case there is no results at all and results.zip does not exist. Todo: catch mailService or zip exception
         //else user left, auto-termination
            mailService.sendMail {
                multipart true
                to "weidewind@gmail.com"
                subject "BCV failed"
                body "Achtung! email: ${email}, sessionId: ${sessionId}"
            }
            mailService.sendMail {
                multipart true
                to "weidewind@gmail.com"
                subject "BCV failed"
                body "Achtung! email: ${email}, sessionId: ${sessionId}"
                attachBytes 'results.zip','application/zip', new File(results).readBytes()

            }
            println (" bcv bad news sent to webmaster; sessionId ${job.sessionId} time ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")



    }

    def sendLogs(String sessionId){
        //just in case there is no results at all and results.zip does not exist. Todo: catch mailService or zip exception

            mailService.sendMail {
                multipart true
                to "weidewind@gmail.com"
                subject "BCV failed"
                body "Achtung! sessionId: ${sessionId}"
            }
            println (" bcv bad news sent to webmaster; sessionId ${sessionId} time ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")


    }



    def zipResults(String sessionId){

        def output = getOutput(sessionId)
        def results = getZipResults(sessionId)
        println "going to zip files, sessionID ${sessionId} time ${System.currentTimeMillis()}"
        println (output)

        def p = ~/.*\.(svg|html|with_names|cluster\.fasta)/
        def filelist = []


        def outputDir = new File(output)
        outputDir.eachDir { chrom ->
            def chromDir = new File(chrom.absolutePath)
            chromDir.eachFileMatch(FileType.FILES, p){ tree ->
                def splittedPath  = tree.absolutePath.split('/')
                println ("going to add ${splittedPath[splittedPath.size()-2]}/${splittedPath[splittedPath.size()-1]} from ${output} to zip list; sessionId ${sessionId}")
                filelist.add("${splittedPath[splittedPath.size()-2]}/${splittedPath[splittedPath.size()-1]}")
            }

        }
        filelist.add("simple_results.html")
        println("results will be placed here ${results}")
        def zipFile = new File("${results}")
        new AntBuilder().zip( basedir: output,
        destFile: zipFile.absolutePath,
        includes: filelist.join( ' ' ) )
    }


    def getResults (String sessionId){
        return outputMap.getAt(sessionId) + "/simple_results.html"
    }

    def getOutput(String sessionId){
        return outputMap.getAt(sessionId)
    }

    def getZipResults(String sessionId){
        return outputMap.getAt(sessionId) + "/results.zip"
    }

    def getExampleFolderName(List fileList){
        def exampleFileNames = []
        for (f in fileList){
            exampleFileNames.add(f.name)
        }
        exampleFileNames.sort()
        def folderName = ""
        for (f in exampleFileNames){
            folderName = folderName + (f.replaceAll(Pattern.compile('\\..*'), ''))
        }
        println folderName
        return folderName
    }

    def checkInput(Bcvjob job, List fileList){
        String errorMessage = ""

        if (!job.validate()) {

            errorMessage = "Some errors occured: "
            job.errors.each {
                errorMessage += "<p>" +  it + "</p>"
            }
            //if (!isFloat(job.distance) || job.distance.toFloat() < 0 || job.distance.toFloat() > 0.1){
            if ( job.distance < 0 || job.distance > 0.1){
                errorMessage += "<p> Maximum distance must not be less than 0 or more than 0.1 </p>"
            }
            if (job.errors.hasFieldErrors("email")){
                errorMessage += "<p>Your e-mail does not seem valid </p>"
            }
            if (job.errors.hasFieldErrors("files") || (fileList.size() == 0 & job.isExample == "false")){
                errorMessage += "<p>Select at least one file </p>"
            }
        }

        if (fileList.size() > 10){
            errorMessage += "<p>Please, do not select more than 10 files at once. </p>"
        }

        if (job.isExample == "false"){
            for (f in fileList) {
                def name = f.getOriginalFilename()
                int dot= name.lastIndexOf(".");
                if (name.substring(dot+1) != "ab1"){
                    errorMessage += "<p>Unsupported extension: ${name} </p>"
                }

                def bytes = f.getBytes()
                if (bytes[0] != 'A' || bytes[1] != 'B' || bytes[2] != 'I' || bytes[3] != 'F' || !(bytes[4]+bytes[5] >= 101)){
                    errorMessage += "<p>Not ABI: ${name} </p>"
                }


            }
        }


        return errorMessage

    }





    def isFloat(String value)
    {
         try
         {
             Float.parseFloat(value);
             return true;
          } catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
          {
              return false;
          }
    }

    def getAbsPath(){
        return Holders.config.absPath
    }

    def getStorePath(){
        return Holders.config.storePath
    }

    def talkWork(){
        ServiceCategory.talkWork()
    }

    def talkQueue(){
        ServiceCategory.talkQueue()
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do something inside one of your domain classes perhaps?  i.e. have you got any inner classes or methods?

Comment: also check your revision control, if there where changes, that moved such a class into another one.  with the clean you might have removed some old `.class` files, that shadowed the problem

Comment: @John, I have custom validators defined in constraints field.

Comment: @weide I'd try without the custom validators and see if you get an issue.  I take it `BcvjobService` is your class, is that something you can share?

Comment: @John Yes, but it's 500 lines long and highly unstructured

Comment: Someone appears to be having the same error here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/groovy-user/wYiGe6eu4f8  Perhaps somewhere in your service you are referencing a variable that doesn't exist?  You could try commenting out the implementation of each method in turn to see if the problem goes away in order to narrow down where the error is?  Also, this (http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882) is a monumentally awesome book and you should consider reading it if you want to make life easier for yourself!

Comment: @John, I will give it a try, thanks. And thank you for the reference too, I definitely need it)

Comment: Resolved. I was removing stale .class files by hands, trying to pinpoint the method/class that caused the problem, and at some point grails gave me a meaningful error concerning Mixins. I removed them, and it solved the problem. Thank you for directions, @John and @cfrick!